# The line of best fit doesn't match the scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Below is my scatter plot with a regression linear.  Just by looking at how the markers are distributed on the plot, I feel like the linear is not covering them correctly. From what i see, it is supposed to be more of a diagonal and a more straight line instead of a curve. here is my code producing the plot:

```
for i in range (len(linkKarmaList)):
    plt.scatter(commentKarmaList[i], linkKarmaList[i], marker="o", s=len(clearModSet[i])*1.0*0.9)
x = numpy.asarray(commentKarmaList)
y = numpy.asarray(linkKarmaList )
plt.plot(numpy.unique(x), numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1))(numpy.unique(x)))
plt.xlabel('Comment Karma ')
plt.ylabel('Link Karma')
plt.title('Link and comment Karma of most popular Forums on reddit')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

Am I interpreting that correctly? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Apparently you have an issue between the fit and the axes.. they're log-log. You should show all your code if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fit a straight line `y = a*x + b`, which doesn't look like a straight line in log-space. Instead, you should be plotting a straight line in log-space.

This comes down to `log(y) = a * log(x) + b`
Which we can then rewrite to `log(y) = log(x^a) + b`
If we then take the exponent of this, we find:
`y = x^a * 10^b` or just `y = C * x^a`, where *C* (=10^b) and *a* are the fitting parameters and *x* and *y* are your data. 
This is the function that makes a straight line in log-log space, which is the function you should try to fit against your data.

Comment: Be careful, `e` and `log` are not inverse of each other (usually).

Comment: Ah of course, I am used to log being the natural logarithm. In this case it seems that it is the log10 variant instead. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you show, I'd say the problem is that in the log-log plot the scatterplot looks more or less like a line.

The problem is that you're fitting against natural values and then plotting in a log-log plot.

Comment: Yes it is a log log. it's a uni assignment and  is supposed to be log log. how can i do it in that case?

Comment: Absolutely, in log-log it looks good. But then you have to fit an exponential to the original data. Make it easy and set it to log-log after you find the fit, if not it just adds clutter makign diagnostics harder.

Comment: In the above code the line that helps find the fit comes already before i set `xscale` and `yscale` to `'log'`. or did i  get you wrong?

Comment: Wait, I'm checking something... in any case, you should be fitting an exponential instead of a line.